# NSIS inetc download file with /CAPTION and /SILENT

Tags: nsis

I wonder if is there anyway to use Inetc plugin to download file with /SILENT & /CAPTION attribute?

I dont want to show the progressbar / download status but I want to put caption to let the user know that right now the installation is downloading file..

Thanks.